# Unused DLLs use more resources during app startup?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compiler-construction

On this MSDN Post, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994639.aspx,

I read this paragraph:

> Reusable code often comes in the form of modules (DLLs) included in a
>   project. Loading these modules requires accessing the disk, and as you
>   can imagine, the cost of doing so can add up. This has the greatest
>   impact on cold startup, but it can have an impact on warm startup,
>   too. In the case of C# and Visual Basic, the CLR tries to delay that
>   cost as much as possible by loading assemblies on demand. That is, the
>   CLR doesn’t load a module until an executed method references it. So,
>   reference only assemblies that are necessary to the launch of your app
>   in startup code so that the CLR doesn’t load unnecessary modules. If
>   you have unused code paths in your startup path that have unnecessary
>   references, you can move these code paths to other methods to avoid
>   the unnecessary loads.

This means to me that referencing unused DLLs would have an impact on startup time. Say, I accidentally reference

> using System.IO

and I never use it in my code, the module still gets loaded at run-time. From my understanding of how compilers work,such code is removed at compile time. In fact, program just before a cold startup is at a low-level language format(at that point, it should be in machine language)

I don't plan on doing that but if the paragraph is correct, i'm afraid I may have misunderstood the fundamental concept of how compilation/language translation works. Is that the case?

Comment: A "using" directive does not create a DLL dependency. (For one thing, there is not a one-to-one relationship between DLLs and namespaces.)

Comment: The paragraph appears to be talking about *unused code paths in your startup path* causing spurious DLL loading. Not unused directives or references.

Comment: You drew the wrong conclusion, it is rather clumsily written.  The just-in-time compiler needs to load *all* of the assemblies that are necessary to compile a method.  But if that method, say, has an if() statement that rarely, or never, gets executed then you'll want to move the body of that statement into another method.  So the jitter doesn't have to compile it.  So it doesn't have to load the assemblies for it.

Comment: What @HansPassant said, + remember, just because you have a class, doesn't mean it will be compiled during execution in its entirety. Only used part of it will be. the `if` example is perfect example. always place most-used condition first in `if-else if-else`. And if other conditions require use of different assembly, do it in different method as Hans suggested. that method will not be jit-compiled and therefore no extra code will be loaded.